# Can't connect to S3 using cyberduck

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cyberduck

I'm trying to connect to my S3 bucket using cyberduck.

I select S3 from the dropdown.
Input into server name: {bucket-name}.s3.amazonaws.com
Access key ID and Secret Access Key into the next two fields.

The bucket appears to load, but upon attempting to click into it, I get the following error:

```
GET /?delimiter=%2F&max-keys=1000&prefix HTTP/1.1
Date: Sat, 23 Aug 2014 22:41:08 GMT
Authorization: AWS {My Access Key Id}:{string of seemingly random alpha numeric characters}
Host: {bucket-name}.s3.amazonaws.com:443
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Cyberduck/4.4.3 (Mac OS X/10.9.4) (x86_64)
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-amz-request-id: {request-id}
x-amz-id-2: {string of seemingly random alpha numeric characters}
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 23 Aug 2014 22:41:08 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
```

I don't know if that error is helpful at all. It suggests to me that the permissions are not configured correctly. I have added a policy to my bucket that looks like this:

```
{
"Id": "{policy id ...",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "{Sid... }",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket-name...}/*",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::{account-id-number...}:root"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

I'm fairly inexperienced with S3 and AWS, so might have made elementary errors/oversights.

Can anyone suggest what might have gone wrong?

**Update**

Being guilty of lazy reading, I neglected to read the first part of the error before the error message, there's a header:

```
Listing directory failed (/{directory name}).

Access Denied. Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance.
```

Comment: I needed to add a "ListBucket" action to the directory as per [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203598/i-need-an-amazon-s3-user-with-full-access-to-a-single-bucket

Comment: You really ought to post an answer as an answer.